# getting error while creating rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i m getting this error when i m creating application in rails 
i type the following command

$rails new myapp

Well all the files do get created . But i also do get some errors.

```
        run  bundle install
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an older version of Bundler that uses some deprecated methods. Try updating bundler:

```
gem update bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors there, just some notifications.  At least the rails guys are warning you before something goes away, which hasn't always been the case.