# rails 3 rake routes not working, no routes shown as output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rake, bundler

When I execute

```
bundle exec rake routes --trace
```

the output is:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:84.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:84.
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
** Invoke routes (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Invoke threadsafe:disabled (first_time)
** Execute threadsafe:disabled
** Execute environment
** Execute routes
```

and here is my config/routes.rb file

```
 Rails_app::Application.routes.draw do

  match '/' => 'pages#show', :id => '1-welcome-page'
  match       ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

end
```

Here is my gem list

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3)
actionpack (3.0.3)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3)
activeresource (3.0.3)
activesupport (3.0.3)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10 ruby)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.1.0, 1.0.10)
erubis (2.6.6)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.6.0)
kgio (2.2.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.17.2)
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2)
mysql2 (0.2.7)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.2.5)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.3)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rmagick (2.13.1)
thin (1.2.7)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
unicorn (3.4.0)
xmpp4r (0.5)
```

Does anyone know why no routes are produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I finally got the routes working.  I think part of the problem was that the app was a Rails 2 app that had been converted into a Rails 3 app.  Anyway what I did was:

```
 1.  Made a simple Rails 3 app, and ran 'bundle exec rake routes' and I could see that that worked, so I knew the current set of libraries wasn't the problem.
 2.  Then I made the config files the same for both apps.
 3.  Also made the 'config/initializer' files the same for both apps.
 4.  Also made the 'config/environments/production.rb' file the same for both apps.
 5.  And that did the trick!
```

Once I had a simple Rails 3 app that worked for 'rake routes', I earlier tried running the debugger on rake routes for both of the apps:

```
 bundle exec rdebug rake routes
```

and stepped through a LOT of the code to see where the two apps took different paths, but since there was so much different between the two apps, I wasn't able to figure out where things were going wrong.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone who runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seem according this question [getting error while creating rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7379124/1195038) taht you should update your bundler version

Comment: I've run 'gem update bundler' and get that there is 'Nothing to update'.  I've tried all of the suggestions to removing the 'Gem.source_index is deprecated' messages and none of them has worked.  But since that message is just a NOTE, I'm not sure if that is the problem.